# Passing conditional data based on URL string and form selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How can we pass the appropriate referral code in the following scenario based on the URL string and color selected?

Form select (Colors):
Red
Blue
Black
White

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="mktrfl">

<select name="color">
  <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="white">White</option>
</select>
```

**Scenario 1:**
If user accesses page with a URL string that includes any CLR parameter, such as testing.com/?CLR=anythinghere, then mktrfl="default"

**Scenario 2:**
If user accesses page with following URL string (testing.com/), 
and selects "Red",
then mktrfl="groupred"

**Scenario 3:**
If user accesses page with following URL string (testing.com/), 
and selects "Blue",
then mktrfl="groupblue"

**Scenario 4:**
If user accesses page with following URL string (testing.com/), 
and selects "Black" or "White",
then mktrfl="default"

Answer (score 0):

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
let param = searchParams.get('CLR')
if(param === 'wbr_42')
mktrfl = 'default'
else {
$('select').on('change', function() {  
   val = $(this).val();
  if( val == 'red')
     mktrfl = 'groupred'
   // so on 
})
}
```